# Moving Text program in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086, x86-16

I am trying to make a program in assembly language in which i want to move a text or character on the screen like a screensaver,i.e, at first it should move in forward as well as in downwards direction. When it hits the lower limit of the screen, it should start moving in forward and upward direction and vice versa.

I have tried myself and i have been able to move the character in forward and downward direction at the same time. When the character hits lower limit of the screen, i want it to move in upward and forward direction but i can't seem to figure how to do it.

I am using emu8086 assembler

```
.model small
.data
st1 db "O",13,10,'$'
.code
main proc
    mov AX,@data
    mov DS,AX 

    mov BL,0
    label1:
    mov AH,2H
    mov BH,0            ;goto-XY
    mov DH,BL
    mov DL,BL
    INT 10H

    mov AH,9H
    mov DX,offset st1      ;print
    INT 21H

    mov AH, 6H 
    mov AL, 0    
    mov BH, 7         ;clear screen 
    mov CX, 0
    mov DL, 79
    mov DH, 24
    int 10H

    ADD BL,1

    cmp DH,23           ;conditional jump
    jz label2
    loop label1 

    label2:

   ; mov AH,2H
   ; mov BH,0            ;goto-XY
   ; mov DH,BL
   ; mov DL,BL
   ; INT 10H

    mov AH,9H
    mov DX,offset st1      ;print
    INT 21H

    mov AH, 6H 
    mov AL, 0    
    mov BH, 7         ;clear screen 
    mov CX, 0
    mov DL, 79
    mov DH, 24
    int 10H

    SUB BL,1
    loop label2

    mov AH,4CH
    INT 21H
end main
```

At the end of each iteration of first loop, i am checking if 'DH' = 23 because lower limit of y-axis of my screen is 23. If lower limit of the screen is reached, it should jump to 'label2' but it does not jumps on to 'label2' which is obviously because i am not using 'cmp' statement correctly.
Can anyone help me solve this problem ?

Main thing that i want help with is what condition should i check in 'label1' to jump to 'label2'.

PS. Just a beginner in  assembly language so if you suggest a solution, please keep it simple and easy to understand. 
Here's what i have tried so far.

Comment: What version of assembly are you using?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by version of assembly. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: There are lots of different versions of assembly language depending upon your architecture. One of the more popular assemblers in nasm.

Comment: What is `st2` ?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez it's a mistake. it's actually st1

Comment: @EliSadoff i am not sure which version is mine.

Comment: That question is "What assembler are you using (to compile this) and what is the target platform?" (I guess MASM or TASM and DOS 16b real mode). BTW, I would first learn how to write to video memory directly, if you want to do "screen saver", then why do you burn 10x more CPU (BIOS calls to output text mode character are extremely inefficient and slow). http://stackoverflow.com/a/40018198/4271923

Comment: @Ped7g i am using emu8086.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems :

- You compare `DH` with `23` to know if the bottom of screen was reached, but `DH` was lost when you cleared the screen. You should compare `BL`.
- Uncomment the block to positionate cursor.

Here is your code fixed :

```
.model small
.data
st1 db "O",13,10,'$'
.code
main proc
    mov AX,@data
    mov DS,AX 

    mov BL,0
    label1:
    mov AH,2H
    mov BH,0            ;goto-XY
    mov DH,BL
    mov DL,BL
    INT 10H

    mov AH,9H
    mov DX,offset st1      ;print
    INT 21H

    mov AH, 6H 
    mov AL, 0    
    mov BH, 7         ;clear screen 
    mov CX, 0
    mov DL, 79
    mov DH, 24
    int 10H

    ADD BL,1

    cmp BL,23         ;◄■■■ COMPARE BL, NOT DH, BECAUSE
    jz label2         ;     YOU LOST DH WHEN CLEARED SCREEN.
    loop label1 

    label2:

    mov AH,2H           ;◄■■■ UNCOMMENT THIS BLOCK !!!
    mov BH,0            ;goto-XY
    mov DH,BL
    mov DL,BL
    INT 10H

    mov AH,9H
    mov DX,offset st1      ;print
    INT 21H

    mov AH, 6H 
    mov AL, 0    
    mov BH, 7         ;clear screen 
    mov CX, 0
    mov DL, 79
    mov DH, 24
    int 10H

    SUB BL,1
    cmp BL,1         ;◄■■■ PERSONAL CHANGE : DETECT WHEN
    jz label1        ;     CURSOR REACHES THE TOP ☻
    loop label2

    mov AH,4CH
    INT 21H
end main
```

Comment: Split second, you answer just a few seconds earlier :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
mov DL, 79
mov DH, 24     <-- here Dh = 24
int 10H

ADD BL,1

cmp DH,23      <- so here condition never true
jz label2
```